# Javascript function parameter with unexpected result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple javascript function that will open a modal dialog. If I pass it a few parameters it will open up with no problem. I'm using jQuery to enable some keyboard functionality on my site. Basically a user will navigate a bunch of table cells, find the value they're looking for and hit 'Enter'. I have an event listener waiting for keyCode 13. When that fires I take the HTML from that cell, run it through a regular expression and pull out a string. I take that string and pass it to my javascript function.

If I hardwire values into the function it works fine, if I pass it the string returned from the regular expression it always fails. If I compare the hardwired value to the the result from the regular expression they are 100% identical. I cannot fathom why the function will not take the variable returned from the regular expression.

Javascript function:

```
function openDetail(event, newWindow, className, methodName, param, param1, param2) {

            param = (typeof param === "undefined") ? "defaultValue" : param;
            param1 = (typeof param1 === "undefined") ? "defaultValue" : param1;
            param2 = (typeof param2 === "undefined") ? "defaultValue" : param2;
            newWindow = (typeof newWindow === "undefined") ? "defaultValue" : newWindow;

            var windowName = '';
            if (newWindow == true) {
                windowName = '#openExtendedDetailWindow';
            } else {
                windowName = '#openDetailWindow';
            }

            param = param.trim();
            param1 = param1.trim();
            param2 = param2.trim();
            var page = "?url=" + className + "/" + methodName + "/" + param + "/" + param1 + "/" + param2;

            $(windowName).dialog({
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                resizable: true,
                modal: true,
                position: 'center',
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load(page, function () {
                    });
                },
                show: {
                    effect: 'fade',
                    duration: 800
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Javascript for my datagrid and keydown event listener:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#warehouseSelection').change(function (event) {
            var warehouse = $('#warehouseSelection').val();
            window.location.replace("?url=FHInventory/index/" + warehouse);
            event.preventDefault();
        });

      var table = $('#contentTable').DataTable({

            "paging": false,
         "jQueryUI": true,
          "scrollX": true,
         columnDefs: [
         {
         targets: [ 0 ],
         orderData: [ 0, 1 ]
         },
         {
         targets: [ 1 ],
         orderData: [ 1, 0 ]
         },
         {
         targets: [ 4 ],
         orderData: [ 4, 0 ]
         }
         ]
        });
       $keys = new $.fn.dataTable.KeyTable( table );

        $("body").on("keydown",$("form.form-horizontal"), function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 13) {

                $url = $keys.fnGetCurrentData();
                alert($url);
                var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
                var matches = regExp.exec($url);
                $params = matches[1];
                alert($params);
                openDetail(String($params));
            }
        });

    });
```

Hardwired HTML (this works),

```
<td>
<a class="masterTooltip" href="" title="Received" onclick="openDetail(event,false,'Inventory','receivedSpecificDate','27934','RADCH6LC0081', '20150117')">0</a>
</td>
```

Comment: The block of code in the `keydown` event is passing a single parameter to the `openDetail` function, which will be being used as the `event` argument within the function - none of the others are specified as they are in the hardwired `onclick` handler

Comment: So you cant dynamically pass comma delimited values from a string into the function? What you're saying does make sense hmm...

Comment: not like that.  I'll put an answer up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your arguments for the function call contained within a comma separated list, which from your comment it sounds like you do, you can use  [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to turn them into an array, [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to add in the event object at the start, then [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
$("body").on("keydown",$("form.form-horizontal"), function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        $url = $keys.fnGetCurrentData();
        alert($url);
        var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
        var matches = regExp.exec($url);
        $params = matches[1];
        alert($params);

        //this assumes that none of your parameters actually have a comma in
        //if they do, you'll need to split up the string into an array 
        //in a different manner
        //It also splices in the current event (e) to the first parameter
        openDetail.apply(this, $params.split(',').splice(0,0,e));
    }
});
```

Comment: None of my parms have commas in them, I still can't get my openDetail to function properly though. I even tried: $params = matches[1];
                var arr = $params.split(',');
               
               openDetail(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[4],arr[5],arr[6]);

Comment: @Waragi Note that `openDetail` is expecting an `event` object as the first parameter.  Whatever you pass as the first parameter needs to have a `preventDefault` method or it will error when it tries to call it.  You may need to refactor the `openDetail` method a bit so it can handle being called from this situation as well.

Comment: Ohh I see...Hm, I can't just pass it an empty event object like I do with my hyperlink?

Comment: Well, you have an event object you can use already - it's passed in as `e` into your keydown handler.  Assuming that `$params` contains the rest of the parameters, I'll update the answer to use it